# Installing Java6 on MacOs Catalina10.15 with brew cask

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to install java6 on my Mac with

`brew cask install java6`

and I'm getting the following error message:

```
==> Downloading https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/041-88384-20191011-3d8da658-d
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'java6'.
==> Installing Cask java6
==> Running installer for java6; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignore
installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
installer: Es ist bereits eine neuere Version dieses Pakets installiert.
==> Purging files for version 1.6.0_65-b14-468 of Cask java6
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sudo -E -- /usr/bin/env LOGNAME=benutzer USER=benutzer USERNAME=benutzer /usr/sbin/installer -pkg /usr/local/Caskroom/java6/1.6.0_65-b14-468/JavaForOSX.pkg -target /` exited with 1. Here's the output:
installer: Cannot install on volume / because it is disabled.
installer: Es ist bereits eine neuere Version dieses Pakets installiert.
```

Apparently it doesn't work because I cannot have different versions of java on the same volume, any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this??

Comment: Java 6 is needed to run SPSS Version 22

Comment: This will not end well.  Consider running a Linux instance instead in a virtual machine.